# Custom validation attribute not working for select list in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I created a simple web form that I'm trying to implement server-side validation on. I created a custom validation attribute for a select list in the form but it's not validating for some reason. What it should do is to check that the submitted value from the select list is not equal to "NULL". I've tried commenting out everything in the attribute code to make it return an error every time and placing a breakpoint too but haven't had any luck with that. I'd appreciate any help!

My code is below:

View model that is passed to the view (**SelectNotNull** is my custom attribute):

```
[SelectNotNull] 
[DisplayName("State:*")]
public string State { get; set; }
public ICollection<SelectListItem> States { get; set; }
```

Custom attribute class:

```
public class SelectNotNullAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string GetErrorMessage() => $"The field cannot be null.";

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string selectValue = value.ToString();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectValue) || selectValue == "NULL")
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

And the relevant code in my .cshtml file:

```
<label asp-for="State"></label>
<select asp-for="State" asp-items="@Model.States">
    <option value="NULL">- Select a State -</option>
</select>
<span asp-validation-for="State"></span>
```

Comment: Blazor validation is different from razor views and pages. Read the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation

Comment: Thanks, JHBonarius. I'll check it out.